# writeToURL not working

Tags: cocoa, http, url

I am trying to use

```
NSString *myString  = @"NO";
[myString writeToURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://example.com/text.txt"] atomically:YES];
```

But am having no luck. myString is set to NO and example.com is set to the correct website. The only issue I could see would be text.txt already existing? Can `writeToURL` even write to http? I can always go back to using `NSTask` and curl but that was a nightmare. :)

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about the NSString version of `writeToURL:atomically:`, but the NSData version says that it only works with `file://` URLs, so I wouldn't be shocked if the NSString version was the same.

Edit to add: the NSString version of `writeToURL:atomically:` is deprecated.  You're supposed to use `writeToURL:atomically:encoding:error:` instead.  Try it and see if the error result tells you anything.

Comment: Hmmm Okay well it looks like its back to curl. Thanks for the part about it being deprecated xcode didn't tell me.